# MySQL, 'WHERE NOT IN' slow

Tags: mysql

I'm having issues with MySQL query running extremely slow. It takes more than 10 min for each one. I've tried to rewrite it using LEFT JOINT, but "joints" are not my best expertise ))

I hope someone will be able to help me.

```
    select subscriberId 
    from segments 
    where (segmentId = 29) 
    and subscriberId not in 
    (select subscriberId from que where (campaignId = 31 or campaignId = 32)) 
    order by rand() 
    limit 20000
```

All indexes are in place. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: sub query may be the problem let look explain

Comment: Yes, subquery is the problem. I understand it. Its running millions of subqueries to get results. Its 100% clear for me. So I'm asking how to optimize it ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your problem is in

```
order by rand()
```

try to delete this and look time.

UPDATE

1. add index:

   `alter table que add index (subscriberId)`
2. try this:

   `select segments.subscriberId from segments
   left join que on que.subscriberId = segments.subscriberId and ( que.campaignId = 31 or que.campaignId = 32 )
   where segments.segmentId = 29 and que.id is null
   limit 20000`

I see 0.08 sec and 0.13 with order by rand().

Don't use phpmyadmin to check, because of it have more time to render result. I'm using console mysql client

`20000 rows in set (0.13 sec)`

mysql> select segments.subscriberId from segments  left join que on que.subscriberId = segments.subscriberId and ( que.campaignId = 31 or que.campaignId = 32 ) where segments.segmentId = 29 and que.id is null order by rand() limit 20000 ;

Comment: Yep, order by rand() is not the fastest, however previously we were not "cutting out" with "not in" and it usually took around 1-2 second which is ok, as it is running in background. Since the system is upgrading and we need to offer more we need to have more detailed segmentation we've added "not in" and it started to to take "years" to process

Comment: Order by rand does'nt use indexes, creates tmp tables and with some weight of data - files. It's really extremelly slow.

Comment: And I wish I could remove order by rand(), but I need to keep this functionality. In this example I need to select 20k rows out of 600k, so it is pretty important to have some rotation.

Comment: Is it a full query? or you show us simple variant with only "select id"?

Comment: Read this: [link](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/ ) about random querys.

Comment: This is full query. subscriberId is not autoincrement id for this table however query might be a bit more complicated like

       where (segmentId = 29 or segmentId = 30) 

for example

Comment: also it is already running more than 6 min without using order by rand(), so actually no difference

Comment: Please, give me SQL of this tables to reproduce the problem. You can update `email` and `name` columsn with 'aaaaa','bbbbb'

Answer (score 1):

Try using a join

```
SELECT sg.subscriberId 
    FROM segments sg JOIN que q 
    ON (sg.subscriberId = q.subscriberId and sg.segmentId = 29)
    WHERE (q.campaignId <> 31 AND q.campaignId <> 32)
```

Comment: Actually it is returning subscriberId values that are in que table, but I need to cut off those values :(

Comment: Still the same. It returns values that are present in que table

Comment: Replacing OR with AND fixed the issue

Comment: Also 1 more little thing if you can help me. If I need to select either segmentId = 29 or segmentId = 30.

Comment: OKAY, I HAVE REPLACED OR WITH AND. IF RIGHT YOU CAN MARK IT AS CORRECT

Comment: THEN JUST ADD THAT IN THE CONDITION. i.e (sg.subscriberId = q.subscriberId and (sg.segmentId = 29 or sg.segmentId = 30)). PLease check it.

Comment: and if we don't have corresponding entries in segments and que nothing is returned, but expected whole segments according to clause

Comment: Yep, but the issue is that subscriberId where segmentId = 30 has no same values in que so whole segemntId = 30 is not in returned

Comment: then try using left join

Comment: The same result. When nothing in common is found nothing is returned

Comment: Are you saying about a condition where segmentId is 30 and since there is no corresponding values in que nothig is returned.

Comment: Yes, table que has no corresponding values to segmentId=30 in 1st table. So it is expected segmentId=30 should be returned as whole.

Comment: so if que table does not have a corresponding entry then the reason for the corresponding segment not appearing can accounted to the where clause

Comment: TRY THIS
SELECT sg.subscriberId 
    FROM segments sg LEFT JOIN que q 
    ON (sg.subscriberId = q.subscriberId and sg.segmentId = 29 OR sg.segmentId = 30)
    WHERE (q.campaignId <> 31 AND q.campaignId <> 32)

Comment: MySQL server didn't return anything. Not an empty result, but just didn't reply.

Comment: CAN YOU GIV THE 2 TABLES

Comment: there is a link to sql files in previous discussion. This question is 100% answered and working as supposed. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `NOT IN` with `NOT EXISTS`

```
select s.subscriberId 
from segments s
where (s.segmentId = 29) 
and NOT EXISTS (select * from que q 
                where s.subscriberId = q.subscriberId AND 
                (q.campaignId = 31 or q.campaignId = 32)) 
order by rand() 
limit 20000
```